# How do a select option selection pick from some other page using HTML and JavaScript only?

Tags: javascript, html, html-select

I have two pages, one where the user chooses an option (A) the other where that option is used (B). When the users have made their choice, they should be redirected to page B.
I have an idea on how to pass the choice value in URL, but how can I retrive the correct option in page B. I am using only HTML and JavaScript. (client side code only please)

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean something like this?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function redirect(sel) {
        var url = sel.options[sel.selectedIndex].value;
        if (url) {
            window.location.href = url;
        }
    }
</script>

<select onchange="redirect(this);">
    <option value="">Please select</option>
    <option value="http://www.google.com/">First (Google)</option>
    <option value="http://www.yahoo.com/">Second (Yahoo)</option>
</select>
```

Comment: No i am asking some other pages to X page, but your solution is X page to some other pages.  Ok anyway it provide the somewhat idea. Thanks for your reply.